# Run Checkmarx on code not in packaging org (too big for Community scanner)

Tags: vs-code, isv, security-review, cicd, checkmarx

I am consulting an ISV partner with their **resubmission of the Salesforce Security Review**.

They ran the initial **Checkmarx** scan using the **[Partner Scanner](https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner/)** on the code in their Packaging org, then fixed the issues in a branch, and now want to rescan. But before actually merging the changes into their Packaging org.

So rescanning using the Package-only based Partner Scanner is NOT possible. Scanning with the **[Community scanner](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner)** also failed as the amount of code is exceeding its limits.

What can we do? What about the **[Checkmarx VSCode Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=checkmarx.cxvscode)**? How and where do I buy credits for that?

Comment: You can run checkmarx by creating a beta, but that necessarily means (for 1GP) deploying the changes to the packaging org. Running checkmarx independently definitely costs money. Is your excellent PMD not good enough for pre-submission checking?

Comment: Thanks Phil for your kind words but no PMD is not able to cover many Security issues like CRUD, FLS, XSS says they require Dynamic Flow across file boundaries and not Static Analysis of single files.

Comment: @PhilW how can I pay for Checkmarx to use it in VSCode? If you have any experience with it please add an answer as there is basically nothing online out Paid Checkmarx services for Salesforce.

Comment: We have avoided paying by always using partner scans. AFAIK you pay checkmarx directly. Check their website.

Comment: I wonder; could they create a temporary 2GP from the same source and scan that?

Comment: @PhilW regarding your PMD comment. In the closer future the Salesforce CLI Scanner with PMD integration is closing the gap described before. Watch this #TDX22 video to learn more https://youtu.be/nBCdx6ysMn0

Comment: I know I am late to the party, but we have our own checkmarx server, precisely for this reason. If you plan to work with several ISVs in the future it may be worth looking into

Comment: @SebastianKessel Can you (maybe in a private chat tell me a bit how that works, what it costs and how good it is?

Comment: Yes! But I can't, for the love of me, figure out how to get a DM sent here. Email me at sebastian.kessel(at)codescience.com and we can get a chat going there